# Would you know a Weekly Calendar template (53 weeks)?

Tags: templates, calendar

Would you know a Weekly Calendar template (53 weeks), similar to the image below?

[image: Calendar]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX . There is almost for everything a package. Except you are like me, but most people arent. Something like this: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/calendar ?

Answer (score 11):

Use TikZ `calendar`.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tgheros,tikz,array}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar}
\begin{document}
\sffamily
\newcommand\daytext[2]{%
  \begin{tabular}{|>{\mdseries\tiny}r|p{1.5cm}|}
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{#1} \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{#2\color{black}} \\[1ex]
    \hline
     6:00 & \\\hline
     7:00 & \\\hline
     8:00 & \\\hline\hline
     9:00 & \\\hline
    10:00 & \\\hline
    11:00 & \\\hline
    12:00 & \\\hline\hline
     1:00 & \\\hline
     2:00 & \\\hline\hline
     3:00 & \\\hline
     4:00 & \\\hline
     5:00 & \\\hline
     6:00 & \\\hline\hline
     7:00 & \\\hline
     8:00 & \\\hline
     9:00 & \\\hline\hline
    10:00 & \\\hline
    11:00 & \\\hline
  \end{tabular}
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \calendar (cal)
  [dates=2016-04-17 to 2016-04-23,day list right,day xshift=3cm,
  day text={\daytext{\%wt}{\Huge\%d-}}]%\ooalign{\Huge\%d-\cr\hidewidth\raisebox{1cm}{\%wt}\hidewidth}}]
  if (weekend) [font=\bfseries]
  if (Sunday) [red];
  \node[above right,font=\bfseries\LARGE] at (cal-2016-04-17.north west)
    {April 17--23, 2016};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It looks really fantastic! 

A question, would you know how to make it automatic maybe with a macro. based on the week number?
In the above model, still, we have to give quite a lot of input data:  (cal-2016-04-17.north west)
    {April 17--23, 2016};

It would be great if we could only indicate that we would like to make a document e.g. from the week #10 to #15 for 2016, and it'll generate the PDF.